# Spray JSON: How to get implicitly declared objects into read and write methods?

Tags: scala, spray, scalatest, spray-json

I am currently struggling with `spray-json` writing a protocol for my data model. For deserialization of JSON data to my data transfer objects, a DAO has to be contacted to check if an appropriate object exists, otherwise a `DeserializationException` should be thrown.

So far, I have the following:

```
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit object MyDtoJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[MyDto] {

    override def write(obj: MyDto): JsValue = // Serialization implementation

    override def read(json: JsValue): MyDto = {
      // parse the JSON, get some parameters, let them be a, b, c
      dtoLookup(a, b, c) match {
        case Some(dto: MyDto) => dto
        case None => throw new DeserializationException("Cannot retrieve object from DAO")
      }
    }
  }

  def dtoLookup(a: SomeType, b: SomeOtherType, c: YetAnotherType)(implicit dao: MyDAO): Option[MyDto] = {
    // lookup the MyDTO with the dao instance
  }
}
```

My test looks like the following:

```
class MyJsonProtocolTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  implicit val MyDAO = // some test instance, can be a mock object

  "The protocol" should "serialize a DTO" in {
    val dto: MyDTO = ...
    dto.toJson.compactPrint should be("{...}")
  }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that it cannot find the implicit `MyDAO` when trying to compile the `MyJSONProtocol`. In [When testing Spray services with Scalatest, how to introduce implicit values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827761/when-testing-spray-services-with-scalatest-how-to-introduce-implicit-values) I asked yesterday, I was suggested to pass in the implicit parameter directly into the method, but I cannot do this here because the `read` method is defined in the `RootJsonFormat`.

When I call the `dtoLookup` method directly from my test code, it succeeds.

So, how do I get the `MyDAO` instance into my special JSON format?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the implicit parameter a constructor parameter to one of the classes being used.  This might require that you turn one of your `objects` into a `class`.  Then you can make an `get` method on the companion object of that class that uses an implicit in scope to construct the class with the desired argument.

This doesn't really have to do with `spray` or `scalatest`, rather it's just an issue with implicits and implicit scope.  Here's a simplified version:

```
object MyJsonProtocol {
  implicit object MyDtoJsonFormat {
    def read(x: Int) = dtoLookup
  }
  def dtoLookup(implicit x: Int) = x + 1
}
```

And you might consider changing that to:

```
class MyJsonProtocol(implicit x: Int) {
  implicit object MyDtoJsonFormat {
    def read(x: Int) = dtoLookup
  }
  def dtoLookup = x + 1
}

object MyJsonProtol {
    def get(implicit x: Int) = new MyJsonProtocol
}
```

And then you can use this with an implicit in scope:

```
class MyJsonProtocolTest {
  implicit val x = 5
  val proto = MyJsonProtol.get
  val myReadValue = proto.MyDtoJsonFormat.read //6
}
```

You can read about the rules for implicit scopes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/1223622), especially relevant might be the "Where do Implicits Come From" section.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But for the problem I wanted to solve I found another solution which I consider "cleaner". I created a "Bridge" `MyDTOBridge` which is a case class and contains all parameters I want to (de)serialize, and use this in my JSON protocol. Then I created a `MyDTOConverter` which has implicit methods converting the `MyDTO` to its bridge and back, where I use the DAO as an implicit parameter. I can then get the `MyDTO` in an `Option` where I can get `None` when the DTO does not exist in the DAO.

Comment: Another question: How do I have to understand the `get` method? Is this called implicitly when I do `new MyJSONProtocol`? Is this similar to `apply`?